# Opposite of the ABS function

Tags: sql

I know that with `ABS()` you can convert negative numbers to positive numbers. 
 
But with what function do you convert a positive number to a negative number? 
Is there even any?

Comment: `abs(<number>) * -1` ?

Comment: I think you missed some mathematics lectures... **ABS** stands for ABSOLUTE VALUE, meaning the SPAN of a number from 0 regardless of its direction (positive or negative). There is no equivalent function that would **selectively** convert a positive number to a negative number. Ig you want to convert any positive number to a negative one, just preside it with a `-` sign (e.g. `- 6` for explicit literal numbers, or `- MyVariable` for a programming variable.

Comment: You are looking for the negative of the absolute value? `-ABS(value)`?

Comment: @FDavidov Actually I did had that math lesson. It is just that I learned it in another language then English. So the name of 
a function does not correspond to the function shortcut name. If you are an English speaker however, it will. And since everything 
is developing further along the way I hoped that there was a function for this now. No need to be rude.

Comment: At no point in time rudeness was intended. So, if that was your perception, please accept my apologies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
-ABS(x)
```

e.g.

```
select -abs(123),-abs(-123)
```

---

```
-abs(123) -abs(-123) 
--------- ---------- 
-123      -123
```